# Model depends on a source which was not found

Tags: sql, dbt

I cannot figure out why the source will not find the table in my database. How do I fix this error?

**Context:**

I have a table in the postgres database: Let's say it's called "my_table". It is in "my_schema".

When I try to select from the table by using the sql code below, but it produces an error.

```
select * from {{source('my_schema', 'my_table')}}


Compilation Error in model my_data (models\source\my_data.sql)
  Model 'model.testdbt.my_data' (models\source\my_data.sql) depends on a source named 'my_schema.my_table' which was not found
```

I did actually make a .yml file to handle this.

`sources.yml`

```
version: 2

sources:
  - name: my_database
    schema: my_schema
    tables:
      - name: my_table
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things here:

1. You need to specify the name of the database where the schema of this table is at; and
2. The name that you give to the source, is the name that you need to use in the model.

So if you have the folllowing:

```yaml
# This is your source.yml file

version: 2

sources:
  - name: my_source_name
    database: my_database
    schema: my_schema
    tables:
      - name: my_table
```

Then your model should look like this:

```sql
with source as (
  select * from {{ source('my_source_name', 'my_table') }}
)
[...]
```